# CSS not loading in FF and IE

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have designed a site and my CSS is not loading in FF and IE. It works perfectly in Chrome and Safari. Can anyone help me Debug?
I am loading the CSS in the following way.

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"` `"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

`<head>`

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

`<title>site title::</title>`

`<!--CSS Files-->`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" type="txt/css" />`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/dark.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

`

Comment: Try to use absolute paths in the `href` like `/stylesheets/style.css` or `http://www.yourdomain.com/stylesheets/style.css`

Comment: Provide a link to your site if you want help. One thing I see is that you load the reset stylesheet after the main one, is that by design?

Comment: Is any of the CSS loading or none at all?

Comment: Everything works perfect in Chrome and Safari. No CSS loading in FF.

Comment: just a comment, but you might also want to consider loading your reset.css before your style.css (this won't solve your problem(an answer below seems to have already solved it)), just seems that resetting after applying all your styles is kinda weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`style.css` is missing an `e` in its `type` attribute value (`txt` should be `text`).

Comment: And IE and FF are picky about MIME-type mismatches. This is exactly what's causing the issue.

Comment: Ok thank you. Let me test. Can there be an issue about UNC paths?